# How to make conditional replacement more efficient in R?

Tags: r, function, coding-efficiency

I replaced multiple variables into the new variable using `case_when`, but I noticed there is a lot of repeated code and I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this.
Basically I want to avoid writing `col_a == ""` every time

```
tt <- df1%>%
  mutate(col_a = case_when(
      col_a == "GK" ~ "Goalkeeper",

      col_a == "RB" |
      col_a == "LB" |
      col_a == "RWB" |
      col_a == "LWB" ~ "Side Back",

      col_a == "LCB" |
      col_a == "CB"|
      col_a == "RCB" ~ "C Defender",

      TRUE ~ col_a))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%in%` -

```
library(dplyr)

tt <- df1%>%
  mutate(col_a = case_when(
    col_a == "GK" ~ "Goalkeeper",
    col_a %in% c("RB","LB","RWB","LWB") ~ "Side Back",
    col_a %in%  c("LCB", "CB", "RCB") ~ "C Defender",
    TRUE ~ col_a))
```